# Parcel ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: parceljs, enoent

I am trying to use `parcel bundler` (What is parcel used for?
Automatic production optimization. `Parcel` optimizes your whole app for production automatically. This includes tree-shaking and minifying your `JavaScript, CSS, and HTML,` resizing and optimizing images, content hashing, automatic code splitting, and much more.)

The file path where my html, css and assets are is:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\WEB DEVELOPMENT\CODING WITH MOSH HTML,CSS\PART 3\main>
```

After typing parcel `index.html` in the terminal it says:

Server running at

```
http://localhost:1234 
C:\Users\Desktop\WEB DEVELOPMENT\CODING WITH MOSH HTML,CSS\PART 3\images\sprite.svg> ENOENT: no such file or directory C:\Users\Desktop\WEB DEVELOPMENT\CODING WITH MOSH HTML,CSS\PART 3\images\sprite.svg>
```

I've tried various things (Using windows 10)
restarting Computer and VSCode
deleting

```
cache/dist folders and doing parcel index.html
deleting and reinstalling the json dependencies/node_modules and then reinstalling parcel-bundler then parcel index.html
```

Basically every other tip I've come across when searching for parcel ENOENT: no such file or directory in Google.